# Recover GIT delete Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

I was trying to add bitbucket to my [existing] project on eclipse so I can commit it and have a GIT to work on, but I screwed up. In my GIT Repository Exploring there were 2 cloned project (the same) so I smartly deleted it to import again. The problem is, in my computer, the local folder with the project got deleted. I need to get my files back (as it was before trying to GIT it). Is there anyway I can do it? I'm desperate, since I've backed up 2 weeks ago and I have modified it a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If Eclipse still has the project you can right click on the project and select `Restore from Local History...`. Eclipse will show you the files it has saved in its file history cache.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't have it anymore. I managed to recover with AVG TuneUp Undelete.